# Download file using fetch with Javascript always corrupt

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

i'm try to download file with javascript when load the window automatically, but the file always get corrupted

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>

        <script>
            function downloadFile(url, fileName) {
            fetch(url, { method: 'get', mode: 'no-cors', referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer' })
                .then(res => res.blob())
                .then(res => {
                    const aElement = document.createElement('a');
                    aElement.setAttribute('download', fileName);
                    const href = URL.createObjectURL(res);
                    aElement.href = href;
                    aElement.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
                    aElement.click();
                    URL.revokeObjectURL(href);
                });
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
        downloadFile('./tes.pdf', 'tes.pdf');
    };
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is my code

why always get file corrupted ?

Comment: How does the file gets corrupted? Is there an Error message? Your code doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: i dont know why, the file is ok, if i change the url to the external url still get corrupted

Comment: Check two things: 1. that you get non-zero length blob in the last `then`, and 2. do not call `revokeObjectURL`  immediately as calling it in the process of download can break the download